# Are there accessible vector interface functions when calling C in R

Tags: c, r, vector

When to use `.Call` or `.C` in `R` related with vector arguments, my current way is to handle some attributes like the length, maximum value, etc., in `R` and then pass those attributes as arguments to `C` functions.

From [R extension](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_106.html), at least a function names `length` is available. So are there similar interfaces in `C` to `R` vector functions like `max`, `min`, `rep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rcpp` has basic functions like `min`, `max` and `rep`. Consider the following example (suppose it's called `example.cpp`):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector exampleMinMax(NumericVector x) {
  NumericVector out(2);
  out[0] = min(x);
  out[1] = max(x);
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector exampleRep(NumericVector x, int n) {
  NumericVector out = rep_each(x, n);
  return out;
}
```

Then in `R` you can do:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("example.cpp")
exampleMinMax(1:10)

[1]  1 10

exampleRep(1:10, 2)

[1]  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9  9 10 10
```

Comment: Turning to Rcpp is reasonable.